# How do I concisely convert a python dictionary to a list of tuples, given a dictionary in which the values may be different types?

Tags: python, dictionary

Important: If the `value` is a list, then I want to get multiple `key, value` tuples for that `key` and each item in the list. The values in the dictionary will be of multiple types, including at least strings, ints, and lists.

I have a solution, below, but I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to do this.

```
# Sample data
d = {'key1': 'string1', 
    'key2': 15, 
    'key3': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']}

# This code does what I want
parameters = []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        parameters.append((k ,v))
    elif isinstance(v, int):
        parameters.append((k, v))
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for x,y in zip(itertools.repeat(k), v):
            parameters.append((x, y))
    else:
        continue

parameters
# [('key1', 'string1'),
#  ('key2', 15),
#  ('key3', 'item1'),
#  ('key3', 'item2'),
#  ('key3', 'item3'),
#  ('key3', 'item4')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shorter version with list comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'key1': 'string1', 'key2': 15, 'key3': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']}
>>> parameters = [(k, v1) for k, v in d.iteritems() for v1 in (v if isinstance(v, list) else [v])]
>>> parameters
[('key3', 'item1'), ('key3', 'item2'), ('key3', 'item3'), ('key3', 'item4'), ('key2', 15), ('key1', 'string1')]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like list comprehensions for readability. Also, I don't see why you need a separate statement for strings and ints. Either you have a list or not.

```
parameters = []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
  if isinstance(v, list):
    parameters.extend([(k, i) for i in v])
  else:
    parameters.append((k, v))
```

Results:

```
>>> parameters
[('key3', 'item1'), ('key3', 'item2'), ('key3', 'item3'), ('key3', 'item4'), ('key2', 15), ('key1', 'string1')]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I checked for strings and ints explicitly only because I wanted to rule out other types that might give me weird tuples that I can't handle downstream.